# primary and foreign key in same table or not

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

i have a category field. each category has at most one parent.
which is better design?

1)one table: category_parent is Foreign key (related to category_id) and category_id is primary key

```
category_id | category_parent | category_name
```

2)two table

table1

```
catgory_id | category_name
```

table2

```
id | category | category_parent
```

category,category_parent are Foreign key (related to category_id) and category_id is primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that each node will only have parent.  For your requirement, the first option is the better design.

The second option is only really mandated if you need a node to have multiple parents.

Comment: what about if most of category has not parent. so most of category_parent is null but in design 2 we have not this problem

Comment: Perfectly okay to have a null parent if an object doesn't have a parent.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the first one as each node will only have one parent. So,there will be no redundancy as the category name cannot be repeated..

If there can be more than one parent then the category name would be repeated in the table. In this case, you would create two tables.

Comment: what about if most of category has not parent. so most of category_parent is null but in design 2 we have not this problem